# Bib(la)tex: multiple citations in one "References" entry + ordering issues

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, multiple-citations

I'm using the `biblatex` package for my thesis (class style: `book` -- although technically I'm using  the `MastersDoctoralThesis` template from Gunn and Patel*).

*source:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Let's say I'm starting to write the thesis from Chapter 2. I cite Ref3 and Ref4 from `topic2.bib` using \cite{Ref3} and \cite{Ref4}; they appear in-text and in the "References" section as [1] and [2]. No problem here, since these are the first citations I've made.
However, what if I wanted to combine Ref3 and Ref4 into one "Reference" entry (so [1] in-text will appear as "[1] Ref3, Ref4" in "References"). In my experience, I would use `\cite{Ref3,*Ref4}`. However, I have found that this is not working here. I've tried using `mcite`, but it seems that Ref4 is simply being... absorbed?

Am I supposed to define a "MySet" command first, and then use `\mcite{MySet,*Ref3,*Ref4}`?

Let's say I now move to Chapter 1. I have just added Ref1 and Ref2 from `topic1.bib` to Chapter 1. These appear in my "References" as [3] Ref1 and [4] Ref2, even though they appear in the text *before* Ref3 and Ref4 of Chapter 2. In other words, my ordering in-text is [3], [4], [1], [2]. How can I fix this?

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex, 
    natbib=true,
    mcite=true,
    style=phys,
    citestyle=numeric,
    biblabel=brackets,
    giveninits=true,
    abbreviate=false,
    doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, eprint=true,
    sortcites=true,
    block=space,
    backref=true, backrefstyle=two,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{topic1.bib}
\addbibresource{topic2.bib}
\addbibresource{topic3.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

...

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

When Mr Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced that he would shortly be celebrating his eleventifirst birthday with a party of special magnificence, there was much talk and excitement in Hobbiton \mcite{Ref1,*Ref2}.
...

\chapter{Chapter Two}

In the land of Mordor \cite{Ref3} where the shadows lie \cite{Ref4}.

...

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

After LaTex + BibTex + 2x LaTex, my bibliography reads as

> **References**
>
> [1] Ref3
>
> [2] Ref4
>
> [3] Ref1

My sincere apologies for asking so many questions in a single post.
Any guidance, as always, is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please consider splitting up your two different questions into two separate questions (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864), that makes your questions easier to answer and more helpful for future readers. Please also consider adding a fully compilable example document instead of just a preamble code snippet.

Comment: `biblatex` has an emulation of `mcite`'s `*` syntax, but it works slightly differently, see §3.9.10 *`mcite`-like Citation Commands* (note that the support for dynamic entry sets with `backend=bibtex,` is limited compared to `backend=biber,`. If you are running an older version of `biblatex` there might not be any set support with BibTeX.)

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your second issue. Do you have separate bibliographies for each chapter? Did you recompile with a full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX run after you added the citations?

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your advice -- I'll be more careful about multiple questions in the future!

Comment: @moewe Regarding issue 1: ```backend=biber``` fails to read my ```aux``` file correctly, I'm afraid. Currently, I've included ```mcite=true```, which groups the references but fails to recognise citations following the asterisk (i.e. in \mcite{Ref1,*Ref2}, only Ref1 appears in the "References".

Comment: You may have to delete your `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files when you switch from `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,`. If you have an editor that runs BibTeX for you, you will also have to tell it to run Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: @moewe Regarding issue 2: Apologies for my lack of clarity! The issue here is that the references are not appearing in the correct order in the text. I tried including ```sortcites=true``` in the preamble, but it had no effect.

Comment: As I said, `biblatex`'s `mcite` emulation has a slightly different syntax. You don't say `\mcite{Ref1,*Ref2}` to cite `Ref1` and `Ref2` at the same time. You need to say `\mcite{MySet,*Ref1,*Ref2}` where `MySet` is a new name that you are now giving to the 'virtual' reference entry consisting of both `Ref1` and `Ref2`.

Comment: "Correct order" can mean many things depending on what exactly you expect. I think I will only be able to say anything useful about that if you can post a fully compilable (yet minimal) example document that shows what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and patience!!  I've made some edits to the question(s), which I hope makes more sense.

Comment: Any reason why you don't accept or upvote the excellent provided answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here

1. The `mcite` compatibility interface of `biblatex` has a slightly different syntax than `mcite`. Details can be found in §3.9.10 mcite-like Citation Commands of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

   In particular `\mcite{Ref1,*Ref2}` will not just add `Ref2` to the bibliography entry of `Ref1`. Instead you will need to say something like `\mcite{myset,*Ref1,*Ref2}` to create a 'virtual' set entry `myset` containing both `Ref1` and `Ref2`.

   Keep in mind that `backend=bibtex,` may not fully support `mcite` and dynamic sets. BibTeX support for a subset of the available features was added in v3.15 (2020-08-16), see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/921 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/985.
2. Because you are loading `style=phys, citestyle=numeric,` you get the sort order `sorting=nty,` so all of your entries are sorted by author, title and year and not by occurrence in the text. I see little point in separating `style` and `citestyle` here, so I suggest you use

   ```
   style=phys,
   ```

   which automatically sets `sorting=none,`.

   Alternatively, if you insist on loading different styles, force `sorting=none,` explicitly and do yourself the favour of specifying `bibstyle=phys,` instead of `style=phys,` so you can see what is going on.

   ```
   bibstyle=phys,
   citestyle=numeric,
   sorting=none,
   ```

With those two issues fixed and using a `.bib` file that is available on every system with `biblatex`, I'd go with

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,singlespacing]{book}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex, 
  natbib=true,
  mcite=true,
  style=phys,
  biblabel=brackets,
  giveninits=true,
  abbreviate=false,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, eprint=true,
  block=space,
  backref=true, backrefstyle=two,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Lorem \mcite{myset,*sigfridsson,*worman}.

\chapter{Chapter Two}
ipsum \cite{nussbaum}
dolor \cite{geer}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography.]

Comment: Issue 2: perfectly fixed with ```bibstyle=phys``` and the preamble suggested -- thank you so much!
Issue 1: persists -- could it be my bibtex version? I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04: BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian), kpathsea version 6.3.1. Biber produces errors but no bibliography.

Comment: @PhysicsHobbit Issue1 is your `biblatex` version. It is too old for the BibTeX emulation that was added in 2020. I think your best bet is trying to get Biber to work. Ask a new question with an MWE about the errors you get.